# `loop was not vectorized: subscript too complex` in Intel Fortran with OpenMP

Tags: fortran, openmp, vectorization, intel-fortran, avx2

I have an issue while trying to parallelize - with OpenMP - and vectorize a nested loop with ifort 14.0.2.

Here's the loop:

```
!$OMP DO schedule(auto)
do ig1 = 1, N_g
  ic1 = (ig1-1) * N_d
  do ig2 = 1, N_t
    ig2index = T(ig2)
    kk = (ig2index-1) * N_d
    ix = p1(1) - p2(1); iy =p1(2) - p2(2); iz = p1(3) - p2(3)
    !dir$ ivdep
    do i = 1, N_d
      k = kk + i
      c = TL(l)%Fg(ix,iy,iz)%D(i)
      Gth(i+ic1) = Gth(i+ic1) + Fth(k)*c
      Gph(i+ic1) = Gph(i+ic1) + Fph(k)*c
    enddo
  enddo
enddo
!$OMP END DO
```

When I try to run parallel or vectorize separately, everything works as expected; but when I try to compile with `-O3 -openmp -axavx -vec-report6`, the report seems to ignore the innermost loop - the one over `i`, and gives me this message **at the line where `c` is initialized**:

`remark: loop was not vectorized: subscript too complex`

which I can't understand.

If the `-openmp` flag is switched off, the loop over `i` gets vectorized and it runs indeed faster giving correct results.

It's maybe useful to mention that the same code is compiled and works as expected with the actual version of Intel compiler, which is **15**.

Is it just a compiler issue?

Can I get it working with the 14.0.2 version anyway?

Comment: I'd guess, that ifort 14 is not [smart](http://prog21.dadgum.com/40.html) enough to evaluate the dependency between `ig1`, `i` and `ic1` if `ig1` is handled by OpenMP. And ifort 15 is smarter.

Comment: Try compiling on ifort 15 with -opt-report. You should get some additional information about the vectorization.